# How do I release a BITMAP struct?

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, resources

After using a BITMAP struct to get a bitmap's information...

```
BITMAP bm;
HBITMAP hBitmap;
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(...);
GetObject(phBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm );
```

How am I supposed to release/free/dispose `bm`?

Tried with `delete` and `DeleteObject`, none worked.

Comment: You haven't allocated or acquired `bm` dynamically, why do you want to "release" it? It's just like any other normal variable, for example you would not wonder how to "release" `int x;` would you? `hBitmap` on the other hand...

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, it says 'no suitable conversion function from "BITMAP" to "void *" exists', whereas `free(&bm) ` throws "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so I am not supposed to release it? Actually I use this code in a splash screen, and would like to remove every reference to the splash screen bitmap after it disappears...

Comment: In other words, deleting hBitmap only is enough/everything I can do?

Comment: @JefreySobreiraSantos I misread it at first.

Comment: Yes that's correct. If it's defined as a local variable inside a function it will be "released" like any other local variable once the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this

```
HBITMAP hBitmap;
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(...);
```

should better/nicer be

```
HANDLE handle = LoadImage(...);
if (NULL == handle)
{
  /*handle error */
}
else
{
  HBITMAP hbitmap = handle;

  {
    BITMAP bm = {0}; /* allocate and
            initialise bm on the stack. */

    GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof bm, &bm);

    /* Use bm here. */

   } /* Have bm be deallocated or at least
          be inaccessible from here on. */

   DeleteObject(hbitmap);
}
```

It is the handle that refers to the resource, which should be freed when not used anymore.

Comment: That extra set of braces are completely unneccesary.  As others have pointed out, there are no resources associated with `bm` - it is just POD.

Answer (score 1):

You would only need to use the operator `delete` if you had allocated the `BITMAP` with the operator `new`. (Modern, idiomatic C++ discourages manual memory management as well, but since you asked about this in your question, there you go).

A `BITMAP` is a struct of POD values dimensions and pixel data, and an `HBITMAP` can be a handle to a `BITMAP` if it is assigned as such. An `HBITMAP` *does* need to be released with a call to `DeleteObject` when it's no longer needed and no longer selected into a DC, even if it was allocated on the stack; a `BITMAP` on the stack will disappear when it goes out of scope.

There is a difference between the operator `delete` and the Windows GDI function `DeleteObject`. `delete` is a C++ keyword for removing objects from the heap; `DeleteObject` is an API call for freeing GDI resources.

Comment: Misread your question. I stumbled over the the "*it*" in here "*even if it was allocated on the stack*". "it" is evil (at least if not used properly/unambiguously ;)). Removing the DV.